# How to update label's value in the WindowsForms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In my program on the **WindowsForms** I have two forms: parent and child. In the **child** form I've changed the value of the variable, which was declared in the independent class.

When I'm closing the **child** form, I need to display a new value of the variable in the label of **parent** form, but I can see only old value. How to update it?

Here how I'm displaying it in the constructor of the **parent** form:

```
label6.Text = indicators.Money + "$";
```

**Edit1:**

Can't understand, why it doesn't update. Code in the parent form:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            computer.ShowDialog();
            label6.Refresh();
        }
```

**Edit2**

Here what I've done. I'm still experimenting with what you advised:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer();
            Code.Indicators indicators = new Code.Indicators();
            if (computer.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                label6.Text = indicators.Money.ToString();
            label6.Refresh();
        }
```

Actually what I need:

[image]

Comment: How are you showing your child form are you using ShowDialog or Show ?

Comment: Are you passing the instance of `indicators` to the child form? Or are you creating a new instance in the child form?

Comment: @MarkHall ShowDialog()

Comment: @DerekW I'm creating a static instance inside the child form

Comment: I would personally just declare a public Property to pass the value in/out of your child form

Comment: @dima: I don't understand what you mean by static instance. Static classes cannot be instantiated and neither can static members be referenced through an instance. See `static` keyword docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: @MarkHall But I can access the value of the variable after closing the child form. I need to update it's value on the parent form.

Comment: Yes you can. it is still available, just do it right after you check for the return value

Comment: @DerekW Hmm.. but it works for me like: **static private Code.Indicators indicators = new Code.Indicators();**. **Indicators** is independent class, where contains variables

Comment: @dima: Okay. I see what you mean now. You have one of these per form? Because if so, the changes in the one instance will not be reflected in the other as `Money` is an non-static member of the class.

Comment: I have already myself do not understand, I'll dig further =)

Comment: @dima: Please see my updated answer per the new information that you have provided.

Comment: With **Edit2** this is not going to work as the instance of the indicators class is not the same as the one in the child form. They are two entirely different references.

Comment: Then I'll try to change architecture and put both to the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Control.Refresh Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) like this:

```
label6.Refresh();
```

**Edit Per Update**

The real issue here is your approach. Here is a pretty simple way of returning a value from a child form which is what you want.

Add a property to your your child form which you can use to access the `Money` amount set from the parent form.

```
public partial class YourChildForm : Form
{   
    public string YourMoney { get; private set; } 
    // The rest of your form code
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var childForm = new YourChildForm();
childForm.ShowDialog();
label6.Text = childForm.YourMoney;
```

Comment: May be it works, but I can't understand, where should I call it? In the child form I can't, because label6 is private. And I have no idea, where to call it in the parent form

Comment: Call it after the `ShowDialog()` method as it blocks the main form from proceeding until the child form is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are stating your are using ShowDialog you can read the value out of your Child form right after you return from the ShowDialog Method. As I stated in the comments I would just create a Public property to set and get the value of your variable.

Try something like this:

```
child.CurrentIndicator = indicators;
    if(child.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK)
        indicators = child.CurrentIndicator;

label6.Text = indicators.Money;
```

create property in your child form something like this;

```
public Indicator CurrentIndicator {get; set;} //You can use automatic properties or have a backing variable
```